# Need help with a math problem (Solvable with Bayes Theorem?) Also involves entropy

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, entropy

The Question goes as follows:

Research has proven that 70% of the men has dark hair and that 25% of the
women is blond. Furthermore it is known that 80% of the blonde women marries a dark-haired
man.

Suppose that the number of men and women is equal, and that every man marries precisely one
woman. Furthermore assume that every person has hair and that dark and blond are the only
possible colours. Denote the hair colour of the man by X, and of the woman by Y .

(a) Determine the probability distributions of both X and Y (i.e. give the probability of each
possible outcome).

(b) Determine the conditional probability distributions (X | Y = blond) and (X | Y = dark).

(c) Calculate H(X) in 3 decimals.

(d) Show that the uncertainty of the man’s hair colour becomes larger if it is known that his
wife has dark hair. Round up to 3 decimals.

If i'd say + is having dark hair and - is having blond hair and <3 is marries

Then i have:

- P(X+) = 0.7
- P(X-) = 0.3
- P(Y+) = 0.75
- P(Y-) = 0.25
- P(Y-| X+) = P(Y- <3 X+) * P(Y-) = 0.8 * 0.25 = 0.2 (Not sure if this
  is correct)
  P(Y-| X-) = opposite of (P(Y- <3 X+)) * P(Y-) = 0.2 * 0.25 = 0.05 (Again not sure if this is correct)

Then I could solve P(X+|Y-) = (P(Y-| X+) *P(X+))/ P(Y-) = (0.2 * 0.25)/0.25 and P(X-| Y-) = (P(Y-|X-) * P(X-))/P(Y-) = (0.05 * 0.3)/0.25 =0.06 with Bayes Theorem.

But I am not sure how to continue and solve P(Y+ | X+) and therefore P(X+ | Y+) and so on.

Thanks in advance for a reply.

Best regards,

Paul

Comment: The details are not clear.  Are we to assume that the couple in question is married?  That is nor stated anywhere.  And what does $H(X)$ mean?

Comment: H(X) means the entropy of and actually there is not anything else stated about the question, so I am just going to assume that P(Y+| X+) means Probability of female having black hair given that she has a man with black hair, so indeed being married.

Comment: $$H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Pi^2 * log2(Pi))$$